# Assigning values from an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

If I define:  `A1 = {1,2,3}` and then press enter I have A1 = `1`.

How can I also assign `2` to B2 and `3` to C3?

Comment: Do you really want your array to move diagonally like you've described?

Answer (score 3):

Select A1:C1, delete the `=`, reinstate it and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Although I have suspicion that the question is written wrong, as is this does not answer the question. This will not will `B2` and `C3` with values 2 and 3.

Comment: what i want is to assign value from an array